# How do I correctly execute an app with parameters in windows using php

Tags: php, windows

I'm stuck with this for a long time.

I am building a cross platform application that will help run certain commands in Linux or windows. It was built for windows using PHP.

In Linux it works just fine.

But in windows when I am trying to execute the below command - it just doesn't work

```
$command = "\"C:\Program Files\some folder\app.exe\" -B backup c:\directory\file.bak";
$output = $exit_code = null;
exec("start ".$command, $output, $exit_code);
```

The above code works if I pass a Linux command.

On windows I get the below error:

[image]

When I try to log the command before it executes I get the command value passed as:

```
^"C:^\Program Files^\some folder^\app.exe^" -B backup c:^\directory^\file.bak
```

Wierd.

I searched and no solutions found online worked :(

Comment: Try using normal slashes instead of backslashes

Comment: That worked. Plus I noticed that in another class before passing the command I was esaping the command. Fixed now. If you post your response as an answer, I can accept it. @PhilipF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you should use normal slashes ('/') instead of backslashes ('/').

Your command should look like this:

```
$command = "\"C:/Program Files/some folder/app.exe\" -B backup c:/directory/file.bak";
```

This is because a backslash is used to [escape](https://www.php.net/manual/de/regexp.reference.escape.php) a character.